# Vim - Tabs in :o Show up as ^I and Autocomplete Does Not Function

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In Vim, my tab's show up as ^I, and I'm wondering if anybody knows why this might be. This is especially annoying when using :o to open a file, as the autocomplete does not function. I've looked all over but haven't been able to find anything, it even occurs with a blank .vimrc file. Is there a setting that would cause this, or a way I can remap the key to get it to function properly?

Answer (score 5):

If I read you correctly, you are talking of autocompletion in command mode when e.g. edit a file.

The section "cmdline-completion" of Vim manual says:

> The 'wildchar' option defaults to  (CTRL-E when in Vi compatible mode)

You should check this option.

OTOH, if :o means "open" command, it's obsolete and not recommended, and I'm wondering why do you use it. Really it's not to open a file, it's to enter visual mode.

If I understood you in a wrong way, please elaborate your question with more details. Currently it's too ambiguous.

Comment: Confirming that `:e` is the way to go if you intended to use `:open`/`:o` as a newbie just to open a new file. Tab works as expected with `:e`

Answer (score 2):

This was happening for me on a Raspberry Pi with a Raspbian Lite - Stretch image (2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite).

The fix for me was to

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

(perhaps vi was being used as default before I installed vim and my `tab` presses on the command line when trying to open a file were being shown as `^I`)

Comment: Nice!  Your answer made me think to check if vim was *actually installed* ... it wasn't! (Apparently I was just using vi the whole time).